# Detect binding error on a custom wpf textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, textbox

I have a custom textbox that has a dependencyProperty called valueProperty of type double nullable. My problem is that the property is binded to doubles nullables and no nullables on the model, and when I try to put a null and the binding value is no nullable, this obviously fails, showing the red rectangle. I want to detect the binding fail and assign a 0 when this occurs. So my question is: is there any way to detect that binding fail?

I know that I can fix it using 2 diferent customsTextbox for nullables and no nullables, and other ways, just wondering if there is a way to check the success of the binding. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT >>>>>**

Model:

```
private double _Temperature;
public double Temperature
{
    get { return _Temperature; }
    set { SetProperty(ref this._Temperature, value); }
}

private double? _Density;
public double? Density
{
    get { return _Density; }
    set { SetProperty(ref this._Density, value); }
}
```

View(simplified):

```
<local:customTextBox Value="{Binding Temperature}"/>
<local:customTextBox Value="{Binding Density}"/>
```

customTextBox dependencyProperty:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty valueProperty =            
DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Value",
        typeof(double?),
        typeof(customTextBox),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnValuePropertyChanged)
        );

    private static void OnValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        customTextBox ctb = d as customTextBox;
        ntb.Value = (double?)e.NewValue;
        //Here I can check the binding fail.
    }
```

**EDIT WITH SOLUTION >>>>>**

There was diferent solutions to my problem, I'll enumerate them:

**@blindmeis** solution. This is the easiest one, but the less potent to:

```
<local:customTextBox Value="{Binding Temperature, TargeNullValue=0}"/>
```

**@Gary H** solution. This is the one I selected as the solution, because it answer exactly what I was asking and also the easier to implement in my current app:

```
private static void OnValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d,     
DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    customTextBox ctb = d as customTextBox;
    ntb.Value = (double?)e.NewValue;
    if (Validation.GetHasError(d)) 
        {
            //The binding have failed
        }
}
```

**@tomab** solution. I think using converters is a good solution to(maybe better), but I still need keeping the customTextBox class because of other dependency properties, and I will need to refactor so much code. I will keep in mind that way for future implementations.

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Have you created your custom `TextBox` specifically for showing `double` values?

Comment: Yes, and some other utilities, like some dependency properties to easyly unit converting(magnitude, units, etc).

Comment: The scenarios you're describing: converting, `nullables`, etc are best handled with converters (`IValueConverter`). Using Dep Properties for them is an overhead. Using a converter you wil be able to handle very easy 'nullable' and other converting issues.

Comment: Null is a valid value sometimes, if not I would not have nullable doubles. How am I gonna distinguish when to convert and when not, from the View, if the binded property is on the viewModel?

Comment: Both directions: VM->view and view->VM are passed through an `IValueConverter`. In that class you will be able to check if is null or not and act accordingly.

Comment: I already know when the value is null, I want to know when the viewModel property is not nullable, is that easy or am I missing something?. Thanks by the way, you are giving me another point of view.

Comment: You know when the value is null but you need to know "inside" binding and not in the ViewModel (altough you can add a new `double` property in VM and update it from original `double?'). I added an answer to explain better how a converter might help you.

Comment: what about TargetNullValue=0 in your binding?

Comment: I think thats the easiest solution @blindmeis...I've used the TargetNullValue in other parts of my code but I didnt remember to use it on that. On the other hand I want to know when the binding fails, but so much thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is a validation error.
You can query for the attached property:

```
var errors=Validation.GetErrors(myTextbox);
```

For handling and customizing validation see:
[Data validation in WPF](http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/)

Comment: I think thats the near approach to what I am asking. I'll surely mark this answer as the solution

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to use a Converter and its advantage is that you can control how you want the output value (which will be displayed) based on any logic you need.

```
public class DoubleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        // if you want to handle `double` too you can uncomment following lines but this is an ugly hack
        // if (value != null && value.GetType() == typeof(double))
        // {
        //    return value;
        // }
        var nullableDouble = (double?)value;
        if (nullableDouble.HasValue)
        {
            return nullableDouble.Value;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And the xaml may look like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:DoubleConverter x:Key="DoubleConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeValue, Converter={StaticResource DoubleConverter}}" />
```

`SomeValue` must be of type `double?`.

Comment: As I said, I have double nullables values and not nullable double values. So, your converter fails when someValue is type of double(not nullable), and the text value is empty, right?

Comment: So your post must be edited because this difference is very confusing. Would like to put some code: a basic property from your VM and then a TextBox from your xaml?

Comment: So you want to use same binding for both `double` and `double?`? If you know in VM this difference then you also know in View if you need to add the converter or not.

Comment: I edited the code to handle all 3 cases: `double`, `double?` with value and `double?` without value. But this solution is ugly and is better to rely on different bindings (e.g. with converter for `double?` and without converter when you have `double`)

Comment: Yes, you are right. And I can make 2 diferent customTextBoxes, as I said in the bottom of the question. Thanks for your answer, you've offered me an interesting point of view.

Comment: As @blindmeis said, `TargetNullValue=0` does the same that the converter, but shorter.

Comment: Indeed, is much more easy to use. Because of your question to detect `binding fail` I choose to suggest the converter-way. Otherwise, the result is same.